# get all values from textboxes via JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a set of textboxes which I want to iterate in order to get a list of their values. So I used the following appraoch:

```
var locations = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(i => {
    var obj = $(this);
    locations.push(obj.value)
});
```

When I debug that, `obj` is the main-window, not the current element within my DOM. Thus `obj.value` just returns `undefined`.

However when I just use `$("input[type=text]").val()` only the very first value is returned.

Comment: Read about `this` in arrow functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: You can change your all input names like this; locations[]. When you fetch them on backend all will come in an array.

Comment: @j08691 Wow, that was simple. Thanks for the hint. Feel free to get an easy accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use snippet in below. `map` function gets all input values one by one with the function in it.

```js
$("#print").on("click",function(){
  var values = $("input[name='location[]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get()
              
  console.log(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' name='location[]'>
<input type='text' name='location[]'>
<input type='text' name='location[]'>
<input type='text' name='location[]'>

<a href='#' id='print'>print</a>
```

Comment: Nice, I like the `map`-call. That´s exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As of the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) an arrow-function "does not have its own binding for `this`". So we replace the arrow-function by a classic function-expression:

```
$("input[type=text]").each(function(i) {
    var obj = $(this);
    locations.push(obj.value)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is help you,

```
var locations = [];
$("input[type=text]").each(function(i){
  var aaa = $(this).val();
  locations.push(aaa);
});
```